# Is it possible to use Stack Overflow like Jira?

Tags: support

I was thinking about if Stack Overflow has a service like that. In short, the cleaned version of Stack Overflow for firms to use for in-house questions.

Comment: [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/)?

Comment: Considering Jira is a primarily a pain & frustration producer, I'd say SO can be drop-in replacement.

Comment: Only you can answer that, as it fully depends on what features of Jira you require and which features SO Teams supplies.

Comment: I wouldn't even suggest that Jira and [so] (for Teams) are comparable, from my experience with the 2 products.

Comment: @yivi  It's even an upgrade; 90% more pain, 103% more frustration, and 242% more bugs that never get patched.

Comment: What do you mean by *"like Jira"*? The same software is being used by ***meta*** sites, like this one—a task the software wasn't designed for at all. It was only to be because Atwood didn't want to spend any more effort than necessary on it ([meta is murder](https://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/)).

Answer (score 3):

## No.

Stack Overflow Inc. has a hard time of keeping track of feature requests using it as it is, and I think they even *switched* to JIRA or some other kind of task tracker.

I could not recommend using this product for that reason.

Comment: They used Trello cards, then they had Zendesk, switched to Jira for 6 to 8 months then switched back to Zendesk because they couldn't get the workflow correctly configured in Jira. So yeah, they switched, back and forth ...

Comment: @rene must be fun to have a corporate spy